# Calculating McFadden's pseudo-$R^2$ in glmnet?

Tags: r-squared, glmnet

How do you calculate the McFadden's pseudo-$R^2$ using the `cv.glmnet` object from the glmnet package?

The `deviance.glmnet` function extracts the deviances, but I need the null (intercept-only) likelihood and the likelihood for the model with lambda that minimizes the cross-validated error.

Here's my code for running glmnet – what's the next step?

```
> fit_lasso <- glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family="poisson", lambda.min.ratio=.001)
> fit_lasso_cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family="poisson", lambda.min.ratio=.001)
```

Comment: Are you asking if there's a function for this, or how to create your own?

Comment: I believe this will require making your own function. Perhaps you could find a way to channel this through the pscl package, but that requires having a glm object. The fact that glmnet doesn't create a glm object can be a barrier many times I have found.